# Which algorithm does Apache Solr use for sorting?

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene

I want to use Solr to sort 10 million rows of data, then use limit to get part of them. just like this:

```
select * from table sort by click limit 0,10
```

Which sort algorithm does Solr use? Quick sort? Bubble sort? Or some other?

Answer (score 5):

You can safely assume that no system that needs to sort millions of values will use Bubble Sort or any other algorithm that is O(n^2) as its base.

Lucene (now with DocValues) primarily uses an implementation of [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), adapted from the python implementation of the same algorithm. This is the same algorithm that is used in recent version of the JDK.

> Timsort is a hybrid stable sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and insertion
>   sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world data.

There is [currently a discussion whether Lucene](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7268) should switch to the JDK version of Timsort instead of keeping its own implementation.

The sources for the different sorting algorithms that Lucene has [is available in core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util).